Storing ref inside ref looses reactivity
I'm having some trouble with refs inside another ref. Whenever I want to access the nested refs, I simply get back the values instead of the actual reactive variable.
The actual use-case involves a Pinia store, but I managed to reduce it to the essential parts.
Here is a Playground that illustrates the issue.
function useBar() {
  const source = ref<number>(42);
  return { source }
}

function useFoo() {
  const data = ref<Record<string, ReturnType<typeof useBar>>>({});
  data.value['test'] = useBar();

  function getSourceType() {
    return typeof data.value['test'].source;
  }

  return { getSourceType, data }
}

Now whenever I call getSourceType, it doesn't return object, but rather number. When accessing data.value['test'].source, all reactivity is gone.
I've also tried using reactive instead of ref, according to a comment in this question, which didn't change the behavior.
What am I missing here?

You misinterpreted the problem, data is mistyped. Reactivity is ok,  but you should use data.value['test'].source instead of data.value['test'].source.value. See https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/reactivity-fundamentals#additional-ref-unwrapping-details

What would be the correct type for data? Also shouldn't getSourceType return object since it's a ref?

You can trust you runtime code which says it's number. It's not a ref, that's the point, check the link. Probably ref<Record<string, UnwrapNestedRef<ReturnType<typeof useBar>>>>({}), had no chance to check. Considering this is not your real case, it could be XY problem that needs to be solved in some other way. Often there's no need to type things in pinia, it's good at inferred types

My goal is actually to have it a ref, not a number. What would I have to change to achieve that? I don't understand why it's not a ref.

Because of ref unwrapping, it's intrinsic to vue and described well in the docs, consider checking it first. You can't have a ref inside a ref. Consider explaining what result you want to achieve and why you need a ref inside a ref. This looks like XY problem

Perfect, thank you for your time. I had to make data a regular object, not a ref. That way the unwrapping didn't happen anymore.

Glad it worked for you. The weak point of non-reactive object is that ref unwrapping may occur again if data becomes reactive accidentally. There are variations to this, like you can use shallowRef/shallowReactive together with markRaw, or use a fake ref like reactive({ value: ... }), or no refs at all and re-create them with toRefs where needed. It depends on the case which will work better

Thanks to Estus Flask for pointing me into the right direction. If a ref is inside a ref and you access it, it will automatically be unwrapped. See the docs here.
In my use-case, I simply had to make the data property a regular object instead of a ref. That way the entries of data are not unwrapped on access and behave like refs (or computeds).
function useBar() {
  const source = ref<number>(42);
  return { source }
}

function useFoo() {
  const data: Record<string, ReturnType<typeof useBar>> = {};
  data['test'] = useBar();

  function getSourceType() {
    return typeof data['test'].source;
  }

  return { getSourceType, data }
}

